# How does a loosely typed language know how to handle different data types?

Tags: loose-typing

I was working on a simple task yesterday, just needed to sum the values in a handful of dropdown menus to display in a textbox via Javascript. Unexpectedly, it was just building a string so instead of giving me the value 4 it gave me "1111". I understand what was happening; but I don't understand *how*.

With a loosely typed language like Javascript or PHP, how does the computer "know" what type to treat something as? If I just type everything as a `var`, how does it differentiate a string from an int from an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the `+` operator will do in Javascript is determined at runtime, when both actual arguments (and their types) are known.

If the runtime sees that one of the arguments is a string, it will do string concatenation. Otherwise it will do numeric addition (if necessary coercing the arguments into numbers).

This logic is coded into the implementation of the `+` operator (or any other function like it). If you looked at it, you would see `if typeof(a) === 'string'` statements (or something very similar) in there.

> If I just type everything as a var

Well, you don't type it at all. The variable has no type, but any actual value that ends up in that variable has a type, and code can inspect that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and perhaps I should've chosen my words more carefully; I meant type as the verb "to type on a keyboard", not type in a programming sense :)

Comment: The downside of this is that whereas for a statically typed language like Java, the compiler can tell you that a certain type does not have a certain method or a certain method does not accept parameters of a certain type before you even start the program, you only get these errors at runtime in Javascript.

Comment: Yea I'm certainly well familiar with the problems of the language haha.

Comment: For Javascript, you can get compile-time type checking fairly easily by moving to Typescript.